# Performance of C native types vs Postgresql C API types

Tags: c, arrays, postgresql

Essentially, my question boils down to:

**Do I bother casting PostgreSQL datatypes to C types**, **or do I bother writing specific cases for handling each PostgreSQL datatype**. Here are some details.

I'm working on some C user defined functions in PostgreSQL which are designed deal with a large number of values, passed in as an array of some PostgreSQL specific numeric type. I don't know the size of the array beforehand, but it can range from 100's to 10's of millions of entries for any of 4 related arrays (value a, pk a, value b, pk b).

My question is, if I am not modifying any of these values from PostgreSQL, is there any conceivable performance benefit to casting these PostgreSQL input datatypes (INT2, INT4, INT8, Float4, Float8) into C datatypes (Int, Float or Double), and controlling function logic with native C datatypes before casting back to PostgreSQL datatypes to return?

For reference, I am implementing the algorithm described here for finding the closest match of any element in a vector Y to each element in a vector  X:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/161458

Pretty new to both C and the PostgreSQL C API, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about e.g. casting the output of `DatumGetFloat8()` to a `double`? There is no need; these are just aliases for native types (e.g. `float8` is defined as [`typedef double float8`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/c.h#L362)).

Comment: Is this true for other postgresql numeric types?

Comment: It's true for all of the integer and floating-point types (you can see the definitions for yourself in [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/c.h)). The `NUMERIC` type is represented as a variable-length [binary-coded decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal), so there is no native C equivalent. They're certainly faster to work with if converted to a `double`, but you cannot safely do so without losing precision.